# How to set vi/vim on ubuntu to default to allowing pasting from clipboard using ctl-shift-c/v

Tags: vim

I would like to be able to use the system default shortcuts to paste from clipboard into the current buffer using the default register. I was not able to discover how to do this from various online sources.

I do have `+clipboard` in the `vim` `:version`.

Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal mode:

```
:nnoremap <c-s-v> "+p
```

For insert mode:

```
:inoremap <c-s-v> <c-o>"+p
```